# Spring boot returning old excel sheet data

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to create a `function` to get the latest Excel data from a server on which my `Spring Boot` application is running. However, my method is returning old data from the time when my `Tomcat` was started. Kindly suggest ways to implement it.

My code:

```java
@GetMapping("/download")
public ResponseEntity download() {
    String fileName = "/sample.xlsx";
    InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(fileName);

    try {
        return ResponseEntity.ok().header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; fileName=" + fileName)  .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/vnd.ms-excel")).body(IOUtils.toByteArray(is));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: `getResourceAsStream` loads data from the classpath, likely from the WAR itself or one of the libraries in the WAR. This will usually be the same data until you replace it by redeploying. If you want to load data from a **file**, you should use `Files.newInputStream` with the path to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved by using `File file = new File("sample.xlsx");`

This worked as it loads the file instantaneously, whereas rest of the filereader methods load the resource from the classpath just once.